# Expresso Store + UPS Shipping add-on - shipping method is not showing up during checkout process

Tags: expresso-store, ups-shipping

I have added and enabled UPS Shipping add-on for Expresso Store, configured all settings but it seems not working in a current (even store_example) checkout flow. Described below how to reproduce that issue.

> During the checkout process on the /checkout page there will be no
>   shipping methods available on the drop down. Then I went to "Continue
>   Billing Details", typed all my billing/shipping details and clicked on
>   "Review Order". From the Confirm Order screen I clicked on Back button
>   and then Back again to /checkout page and now I have got Shipping
>   methods available, but when new cart is created Shipping methods are
>   gone again.

Any clue what is going on there? So far now word from Expresso Store dev team on that issue and it is kind of serious stuck for me (shipping comes as 0 each time when customer follow checkout steps).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store can't calculate shipping costs without a shipping address specified. Exactly which fields are required depends on the shipping plugin, but with UPS for example generally you require at least a country and ZIP code.

You can set a default country/state under Store > Settings > Countries / States.

Then I suggest you put a `shipping_postcode` field on the first page of your checkout, so that customers can enter their ZIP and click Update to see the available shipping options.

Alternatively, you can ask the customer to choose a shipping option *after* they have entered their full address, which will ensure the correct shipping options are displayed to them.

Comment: I think last proposed options will be the way to go. Based on my experience you should to update your Store Example checkout process, because currently is confusing, as you see.

Comment: I agree - we will take a look at improving the example flow. It works better for the default shipping options, but when you are using shipping extensions there is certainly room for improvement.

Comment: I have pushed Shipping in checkout process after Billing/Shipping data. My question is if there is a way to auto update shipping cost on page load, because it still require to hit Update Total to get shipping cost for first option.

Comment: Also how can I make ZIP code field required (it is when UPS shipping add-on is used)?

Comment: You can either use AJAX to update the totals, or automatically trigger a reload of the page. To make ZIP required, add `require="postcode"` to the checkout tag, same as any other field.

Comment: Just to be clear with AJAX part - I need to execute 'update total' on drop down option change, but how can I get it to load by default when page is loaded for a first time? It always comes as 0 value and customer can click to go further with "free" shipping which is not true. Or how to make first choice as an empty value and then make shipping option field required?

Comment: Well, I'm kind of stuck on that. More here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20327/expresso-store-ajax-shipping-cost-update