# Expresso Store: AJAX shipping cost update

Tags: expresso-store, ajax, shipping

I'm kind of stuck on getting AJAX shipping cost update for Expresso Store.

Shipping part in the checkout page looks like:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Shipping</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                {field:shipping_method}
                {if error:shipping_method}<p class="help-block">{error:shipping_method}</p>{/if}
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right"><div id="order_shipping">{embed="cart/shipping"}</div></td>
        </tr>
```

then "cart/shipping" include looks like:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
{order_shipping}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

All works fine when I use "Update Total", but my goal is to update shipping cost on shipping method select using AJAX below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shipping_method").change(function() {

        var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
        var data = $("#shipping_method").val();

        $.post(url, data, function() {
            $("#order_shipping").load("/cart/shipping");
        });
        return false;       

    });
});
</script>
```

In that case I'm not able to retrieve updated shipping cost.

Any clue where I have made an error?

**UPDATE**

"cart/shipping" updated to:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
<div id="oso">{order_shipping}</div>
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

And AJAX part looks now like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shipping_method").change(function() {

        var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
        var data = $(this.form).serialize();

        $.post(url, data, function() {
            $("#order_shipping").load("/cart/shipping #oso);
        });
        return false;       

    });
});
```

It can retrieve shipping cost, but initial cost for the shipping, when checkout process is started, it becomes selected first from the shipping method list but with real value of 0. I have try to `.prepend` empty option field, but no matter what is selecting first shipping method for new carts (I'm using UPS shipping module). Default shipping method for new carts from the Store settings is not working either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some guidance from Ahmad Saad below (thanks Ahmad!) I was able to get shipping (and total) calculated after shipping method change.

First it will require to change template where shipping form field is located. That part is required due to default shipping value is not loaded when new cart created (in my case). My looks like:

```
<tr>
<td>Shipping</td>
<td colspan="2">
<select id="shipping_method" name="shipping_method">
<option>Choose Shipping Method</option>
{shipping_method_options}
</select>
{if error:shipping_method}<p class="help-block">{error:shipping_method}</p>{/if}
</td>
<td style="text-align:right"><div id="order_shipping">{embed="cart/shipping"}</div></td>
</tr>
```

and AJAX part handling JSON response:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shipping_method").change(function() {

        var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
        var p_data = $(this.form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: p_data,
            context: this,
            error: function () {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (response) {
                 $("#order_shipping").html(response.order_shipping_total);
                 $("#order_total").html(response.order_total);               
            }
        });


        return false;       

    });
});
```

No clue why guys from Expresso Store didn't included that in their code by default :\

Hope it will help other Expresso Store users.

Answer (score 1):

as answer for your last update change your code to :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#shipping_method").change(function() {

        var url = $(this.form).attr('action');
        var p_data = $(this.form).serialize();

        $.post(url, p_data , function(data) {
            var new_shipping = $('<div />').append(data).find('#oso').html();
            $("#order_shipping").html(new_shipping);
        });
        return false;       

    });
});
```

try it and let me know.

Regard's.

Comment: I have done that before but in return I have got full Expresso Store form once again in `order_shipping` div.

Comment: I'm in an extremely similar situation and tried the updated instructions (both options), not working though (no refresh, no error, selection feels empty).

Comment: Updated code returns some kind of "garbage" data :\

Comment: OP updated. Site currently is on a staging environment not accessible for the public.

Comment: check it now, I hope this will do the trick

Comment: Now response is an array (looks like JSON) not calculated value. Updated version from OP is so far closest one, but has issue with default value for new carts.

Comment: can you post this response

Comment: I am really don't know what else you can do , if you can arrange a test page so I can see what actually happened there.

Comment: @AhmadSaad - I have got your code to work and JSON output part for shipping looks like `"order_shipping_val":18.79,"order_shipping_discount_val":0,"order_shipping_inc_discount":"$18.79","order_shipping_inc_discount_val":18.79,"order_shipping_tax_val":0,"order_shipping_inc_tax":"$18.79","order_shipping_inc_tax_val":18.79,"order_shipping_total_val":18.79"`

Comment: Also `new_shipping` comes as `TypeError: new_shipping is not a function` in a console

Comment: hi I think I find your problem , but can you please post the all code for the checkout template.

Comment: Check my answer - I have got that to work following your method.